# How to move MySQL partitions from one machine to another?

Tags: mysql, partition, database-administration, migration

I have a MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
tweet_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
author_id INT NOT NULL,
text CHAR(140) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tweet_id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY HASH(tweet_id)
PARTITIONS 12;
```

How do I move selected partitions from this table to a different machine?

For example, I'd want to move partitions 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 of the above 12 partitions to a different machine. And I'd need to make sure the auto-increment PK "tweet_id" remains unchanged during the migration.

Is there a way to move an entire MySQL partition from one machine to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have plenty of MySQL experience, but I don't have any experience with MySQL partitions, however, I was able to dig up the following URL.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,199428,199428